# How can I play a YouTube video in Unity if given the YouTube URL link?

Tags: unity, c#

How can I play a YouTube video in Unity if given the YouTube URL link? I am using 2019.4.13

Is there a way to open webpages?

Comment: It depends on platform (not every platform is supported by some plugins). There are a few plugins that can do that: e.g. https://github.com/gree/unity-webview

Comment: I actually am noodling on this problem right now, and wrote a little test of playing a Youtube video on a Video Player component. Thing is, I'm not sure if getting the mp4 URL the way I did is kosher (felt pretty hacky while I was doing it) so I'm gonna refrain from posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unity can't play youtube videos out of the box. Youtube generally doesn't support streaming of videos outside of YouTube itself (or an iframe with the YouTube player widget within another website).

There are tools that download youtube videos, however these violate YouTube's terms of service so I would not recommend using them.

Comment: I recall AudioShield used to let you play a YouTube video in-game to use its audio track for the gameplay, [but subsequently patched-out that feature](https://uploadvr.com/audioshield-has-lost-youtube-streaming-dev-working-on-solution/). I'd suspect terms of use or API limitations might have been a factor there.

Comment: Yeah, that's my thinking as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure downloading a YouTube video is a violation of it's terms of service. I can double-check and come back.

Comment: The following restrictions apply to your use of the Service. You are not allowed to:

access, reproduce, download, distribute, transmit, broadcast, display, sell, license, alter, modify or otherwise use any part of the Service or any Content except: (a) as expressly authorized by the Service; or (b) with prior written permission from YouTube and, if applicable, the respective rights holders;

Comment: @FluffytheTogekiss thanks for the verification. I edited my answer to reflect this (and removed the link to the tool since it violates those terms)

Comment: Yeah, no problem!

Comment: The only (legal) possibility, at this point, would be if Youtube itself (well Google in other words) was to release an official plugin for Unity through the Unity store. Such plugin/asset would ultimately be like the HTML widget currently available for websites.
For Youtube, this can't be a win-win situation because its main reason to do it would be $ and as ads would be kinda mandatory (or a subscription), it would more than likely backfire when used in an App or Game.